# Replace :text: with my own gif in a folder

Tags: javascript

i have actually a script that replace my text with emoji in a cdn.

here the demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/w7hcdbpe/

But i'm here to ask if there's a solution to use my own gif in a folder.

can someone help me to build an array that replace `:smile:` with `img src="path/to/my/gif"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do that many changes. Quick and dirty:

In the array at the top it should look like this (without .gif):

```
':smile:': 'mysmilie1',
'!(': 'mysmilie2',
'!o': 'mysmilie3',
```

Line 18:

```
  mapIdsToPaths(emoticons, 'https://yoururl.com/myowngifs/','','');
```

Line 36:

```
emotes[id] = url + prefix + emotes[id] + size + '.gif';
```

Remember: This is a very very very very dirty changing of the script just to fit what you asked for.
The clean way would be removing unnecessary parts you don't need, like "size" or whatever. Or learn how to write your own script. ;)

Comment: can u explain why is dirty, i would learn how to clean up this code :)

Comment: Well, this script you use is maybe "larger" than need. For example if you do not need different sizes or the prefix there is no need to use them as a variable at all. So get rid of what you don't need to get a cleaner solution.

Removing "prefix" and "size" from the function "mapIdsToPaths" will let you remove the the ,'','' in the code on line 18. 

This scipt has been written by someone who wanted to use them, if you don't need them, get rid of it.